# How do I reset an email form after submission so that another email can be sent without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I have this form I've been playing around with in Wordpress.

It works, but here is the problem...

When the page loads, the contact form is blank (obviously)

If info is not put in text fields, form will not send (obviously)

If info IS put in text fields it will send, "Submit" button will disable and the text on the "Submit" button will change from "Submit Message" to "Submitting, please wait..."

When message has finished sending, a "success message" will pop up over the form for 2.5 seconds, the input fields will be cleared back to a blank form, "Submit" button text reverts back to original "Submit Message" text.

*Now*, **WITHOUT** refreshing the page, I want to send a **NEW** message using the blank form.

I fill in all fields, hit send, and I get an error message saying "Invalid email. You must enter at least one email address." - (the source of this message, I have no idea... I didn't make it, and I have searched high and low through Wordpress files and cannot find where it is coming from)

This error message is referring to the "mail to" email address, which the code pulls from the Wordpress Admin settings.

For some reason, after the form is submitted the first time, it "uses" that mail-to address, and will not allow it to be used again unless the page is reset.

Is there a solution here so that I can send a message... form will automatically clear... I can send a new message, form will automatically clear... I can send a new message... and so on, WITHOUT having to refresh the page after each message submission.

Here is the code:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Contact Form */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="top-div"></div>
<div id="container">
<div id="inner-headline">
      <h2>

        <?php 
    $headline = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_headline", $single = false);
    if(!empty($headline[0]) )
    {
      echo $headline[0];
    }
    else
    {
      the_title();
    }
    ?>

       </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="content">      
       <div id="content-inner">
          <div class="sideright-left-col">

            <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

       <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

       <?php the_content(); ?>

           <?php if(isset($hasError) || isset($captchaError)): ?>
              <p class="error"><?php _e('There was an error submitting the form.',          
                      'Sona')?><p>

                   <?php endif ?>

           <div id="status"></div>
           <form action=() id="contact-form" method="post">

          <div class="name">
             <label for="contactName"><span style="color: red;">*&nbsp</span>
                           <?php _e( 'Name', 'Sona' ); ?>:
                         </label>

             <input type="text" name="contactName" id="contactName" 
                          value="<?php if(isset($_POST['contactName'])) echo    
                          $_POST['contactName'];?>" class="requiredField txt"/>

             <?php if(isset($nameError) && $nameError != ''): ?><span 
                           class="error"><?php echo $nameError;?></span><?php endif;?>

                         <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>

                      <div class="email">
             <label for="email"><span style="color: red;">*&nbsp</span>
                           <?php _e( 'E-mail', 'Sona' ); ?>:
                         </label>

                         <input type="text" name="email" id="email" 
                          value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])) echo 
                          $_POST['email'];?>" class="requiredField email txt" />

             <?php if(isset($emailError) && $emailError != ''): ?><span  
                           class="error"><?php echo $emailError;?></span><?php endif;?>

             <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>

                      <div class="subject">
             <label for="subject"><span style="color: red;">*&nbsp</span>
                         <?php _e( 'Subject', 'Sona' ); ?>:</label>
             <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" 
                          value="<?php if(isset($_POST['subject'])) echo 
                          $_POST['subject'];?>" class="requiredField txt"/>

             <?php if(isset($subjectError) && $subjectError != ''): ?><span  
                           class="error"><?php echo $subjectError;?></span><?php endif;?>

             <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>

                         <div class="clear"></div>

                      <div class="message">
             <label for="message"><span style="color: red;">*&nbsp</span>
                         <?php _e( 'Message', 'Sona' ); ?>:</label>
               <textarea name="message" cols="100" rows="200" id="message" 
                            class="txt requiredField"><?php echo isset($_POST['message']) && 
                            $_POST['message']!='' ?  stripslashes($_POST['message'])  : ''?>
                           </textarea>

                         <?php if(isset($messageError) && $messageError != '') { ?><span  
                           class="error"><?php echo $messageError;?></span> <?php } ?>

                         <div class="clear"></div>
           </div>
           <div>
              <?php 
                 $al_options = get_option('al_general_settings'); 
                 $options = array(                       
                                               $al_options['al_contact_error_message'],                  
                                               $al_options['al_contact_success_message'],
                                   $al_options['al_subject'],                                                    
                                               $al_options['al_email_address'],
                              );
              ?>

              <input type="hidden" name = "options" value="
                           <?php echo implode(',', $options) ?>" />

                          <br />

                          <input type="submit" class="button white-back" 
                           value="Submit Message" tabindex="5" id="submit" name="send"/>

                          <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
                </form>
                </div>

        <div class="sideright-right-col">
                    <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Contact 
                      Sidebar") ) : ?> <?php   endif;?>
                </div>  
                <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
      </div>         
    </div>
  <!-- END CONTENT -->
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("#contact-form").validate({
 submitHandler: function() {

     var postvalues =  jQuery("#contact-form").serialize();

     jQuery('#submit').attr('disabled',"disabled");
     jQuery('#submit').attr('value', "Submitting, please wait...");

     jQuery.ajax
     ({
       type: "POST",
       url: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/contact-form.php",
       data: postvalues,
       success: function(response)
      {
        jQuery('#status').addClass('success-
                   message').html(response).show().delay(2500).fadeOut();
        jQuery('input:not(#submit)').val("");
        jQuery('textarea').val("");

        jQuery('#submit').attr('value', "Submit Message");
            jQuery('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
      }
     });

      return false;

          },
      focusInvalid: true,
      focusCleanup: false,
      rules: 
      {
    contactName: {required: true},
    email: {required: true, minlength: 6,maxlength: 50, email:true},
    message: {required: true},
    subject: {required: true}
      },

      messages: 
      {
    contactName: {required: "<?php _e( 'This field is required', 'Sona' ); ?>"},
    email: {required: "<?php _e( 'This field is required', 'Sona' ); ?>", 
            email: "<?php _e( 'Please provide a valid e-mail address.', 'Sona' ); ?>"},
    message: {required: "<?php _e( 'This field is required', 'Sona' ); ?>"},
    subject: {required: "<?php _e( 'This field is required', 'Sona' ); ?>"}
      },

      errorPlacement: function(error, element) 
      {
    error.insertAfter(element);
      },
      invalidHandler: function()
      {
    jQuery("body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
      }
       });
       });

</script>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Just so I'm clear here... (because some rude individual just told me I shouldn't code because I can't read)... the #ID's are as follows.... #contactName = Person's first and last name... #email = Person's email (the person SENDING the email.. not receiving)... #subject = "Duh"... #message... another "Duh"

Comment: I apologize if there is something blatantly obvious in this code that I am missing, but I am new to this stuff and trying to learn... so please... no more rude comments about me "not being able to read"

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Inside your ajax response section after submitting the form you got success message ,

So just clear current forms like below.

```
jQuery.ajax
     ({
       type: "POST",
       url: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/contact-form.php",
       data: postvalues,
       success: function(response)
      {
        jQuery('#status').addClass('success-
                   message').html(response).show().delay(2500).fadeOut();
       // to clear all inputs
       //jQuery("#contact-form input").val('');
       jQuery("#contact-form input.requiredField").val('');
       jQuery('#message').val("");

        jQuery('input:not(#submit)').val("");

        jQuery('#submit').attr('value', "Submit Message");
            jQuery('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
      }
     });
```

Hope its helps..

Comment: unfortunately no :( .... now when the "Submit" button is clicked its loading a wordpress 404 page... here is the website if looking at it will help any www.allentownalive.org/contact-us/

Comment: actually.. there was an error in your code.. you had #contact-formt... with an extra "t" at the end... I'll try again

Comment: Try my edits i found some hidden  fields in the form those are also input so it will get cleared by the code so use only required fields

Comment: I just tried again with the edits, and I'm still getting that 404 page.. the submit button is trying to refresh the entire page it seems, rather than just running through the jQuery like it was before... I've reverted the code back to what is posted in my question... if you go to www.allentownalive.org/contact-us/ you can see how it should work... but try sending a 2nd email after the form clears and it will throw back an error

Comment: actually, I figured it out... I had to add an ID for the $al_options (#options) and then add that to  jQuery('input:not(#submit)').val("");... so its now  jQuery('input:not(#submit, #options)').val("");    My code to clear the form wasn't excluding that hidden input... I wouldn't have thought of that if it hadn't been for your comment about clearing only required fields so THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
         <?php 
             $al_options = get_option('al_general_settings'); 
             $options = array(                       
                               $al_options['al_contact_error_message'],                  
                               $al_options['al_contact_success_message'],
                               $al_options['al_subject'],                                                    
                               $al_options['al_email_address'],
                             );
          ?>

          <input type="hidden" name = "options" value="<?php echo implode(',', $options) ?>" />
```

Add new ID to the input and call it #options

```
          <input id="options" type="hidden" name = "options" value="<?php.....
```

ADD #options to...

```
          jQuery('input:not(#submit)').val("");
```

So now it reads...

```
          jQuery('input:not(#submit, #options)').val("");
```

Bingo!